# MariaDB ability to work in parallel across multiple db users

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How exactly does MariaDB handle the scenario with multiple users and one of them hits some sort of a limit. How would this affect other users?

I would assume one user's 120 second query would not shut down the db for others?

Any links to official documentations much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Each connection is controlled by its own limits.  The limits are initialized by global settings, but run independently for each connection.

Separate connections will be accessing common resources, so there will some *contention* (CPU, I/O, etc), but not of the type you described.

"What you do in Vegas stays in Vegas."